# What are the weights in the 'emdist' package?

Tags: r, earth-movers-distance

Below I compute one earth-mover distance and then another one just by dividing the weights:

```r
library(emdist)
set.seed(666)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(12)
# weights:
wx <- rep(1, 10)
wy <- rep(1, 12)

# distances:
emdw(x, wx, y, wy)
# 0.2417742
emdw(x, wx, y, wy/10)
# 0.125035
```

Why do I get different results? I thought that the weights played a role only through their normalizations (`w / sum(w)`) but as we can see this is not true. The weights do not define the probability masses of the distributions? I read the doc but this didn't help me.

Comment: 'weights' means at least [three different things](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2020/08/04/weights-in-statistics/) in statistics, the documentation doesn't say. My reading is that this is actually the *density* of the distribution at coordinates defined by `x` and `y`?